# Programmatically select a specific TreeViewItem into an unbound TreeView

Tags: c#, silverlight, treeview, code-behind

In the code behind of my Silverlight application, I have the need to re-populate the TreeView and then make a specific TreeViewItem selected.

The code itself is pretty simple, here it is (**i'll trim and pseudo-code-ify it to make it as short as possible**)

```
private void Button_Click()
{
    Guid idToSelect = TellMeWhatToSelect();
    List<myObject> myDataList = myObjectRepository.RetrieveData().ToList();

    myTreeView.Items.Clear();
    foreach(myObject o in myDataList)
    {
        myTreeView.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Content = o.DataField, Tag = o.Id });
    }

    myTreeView.Items.First(o => ((Guid)(o as TreeViewItem).Tag).Equals(idToSelect)).IsSelected = true;

}
```

That's basically it: i'm reading some data into `myDataList`, then i cycle through it and create as many `TreeViewItem`s as needed in order to display the data.

Problem is, `myTreeView.SelectedItem` is null at the end of this, and `SelectionChanged` event isn't triggered. I would think that, since `Items` collection has been cleared and re-filled, switching `IsSelected` on one of the items would act like clicking, but it seems it doesn't).

Oddly enough (for me at least), issuing `myTreeView.Items.First().IsSelected = true;` by itself (that is, calling a method with that single line of code inside) works as expected: `SelectedItem` is there and all events are fired appropriateyl.

What's wrong with my code and/or what am I missing ? Looks like cleaning items up kind of breaks something.

I'm fairly sure others have had similar issues, but a bunch of searches I tried didn't help (most of the info & questions I came up with are WPF-related).

Thanks for your time, I'll provide more info if needed. Also, sorry for the wall of text.

**UPDATE**

Modifying code like this, now the method works as expected.

```
private void Button_Click()
{
    Guid idToSelect = TellMeWhatToSelect();
    List<myObject> myDataList = myObjectRepository.RetrieveData().ToList();

    myTreeView.Items.Clear();
    foreach(myObject o in myDataList)
    {
        myTreeView.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Content = o.DataField, Tag = o.Id });
    }

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>
    {        
        myTreeView.Items.First(o => ((Guid)(o as TreeViewItem).Tag).Equals(idToSelect)).IsSelected = true;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set property `IsSelected` inside of [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190259%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: Right on the spot! Going to update my question to show the updated code. Thank you very much.

Comment: Let me add some explanation: As I understand this correct you tried to update visual appearance of control before it was build.

Comment: Yes, that must have been the issue. Oddly enough, I could see the selection "move" as the selection box in fact *was* changed, but the application 'thought' there wasn't any selection.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while ago, I've solved by calling the UpdateLayout method from the treeview before setting the TreeViewItem as selected.Like this:

```
 myTreeView.UpdateLayout();   
 myTreeView.Items.First(o => ((Guid)(o as TreeViewItem).Tag).Equals(idToSelect)).IsSelected = true;
```